# The existence of boundary defining function

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. For each $x\in\partial\Omega$ there exist a ball $B(x,r)$ and a function $f\in C^1(B(x,r),\mathbb{R})$ with the property $\nabla f\neq 0$ on $B(x,r)\cap\partial\Omega$, such that

$$
B(x,r)\cap\Omega=\{x\in B(x,r): f(x)<0\}
$$
$$
B(x,r)\cap\Omega^c=\{x\in B(x,r): f(x)>0\}
$$
$$
B(x,r)\cap\partial\Omega=\{x\in B(x,r): f(x)=0\}
$$

My question:

Prove that if $\Omega$ is bounded, then there exists a function $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\nabla g\neq0$ on $\partial\Omega$ such that
$$
\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:g(x)<0\},\ \partial \Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:g(x)=0\}
$$
Since $f$ is only defined locally, I do not know how to make use of it. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try a partition of unity.